# Typo3 6.2 add a css class on a content element "image"

Tags: image, typo3-6.2.x

I add an image in the backend as content element. The type of this content element is "image". How can I add a css class to this img-tag?

I want something like this:

```
<img class="responsive" src="xyz.jpg"/>
```

Ho can I add a class on this image tag?

My approach:

```
temp.pics =CONTENT
temp.pics {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        selectFields = image
        pidInList.data = 52
        andWhere = colPos=3
    }
    innerWrap = class="responsive" |

}
```

My approach isn't really ready.

Comment: I found a simple work around: Add a border (Rahmen) "border1" (Rahmen1) to the image. So, typo3 wrap the image with a `<div class="csc-frame-frame1">`. Now I use the following css:  `div.csc-frame-frame1 img {
 width: 100%;
}` I let the question open for some time. In the hope of a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to apply the class to all images, you could add this line to your typoscript.

```
tt_content.image.20.1.params = class="class1"
```

If you only want the class to be added on certain images,I would recommend to use the layout field of content elements (or the alignement). You can then use the if-Statement, a condition or a CASE-object like this:

```
tt_content.image.20.1.params.cObject = CASE
tt_content.image.20.1.params.cObject {
  key.field = layout
  default = TEXT
  default.value = class="class1"
  1 = TEXT
  1.value = class="class2"
  2 = TEXT
  2.value = class="class3"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. And in my TSconfig I add the following code to rename e.g. Layout 2: `TCEFORM.tt_content.layout.altLabels.2 = newName`

Comment: i put it  in both constant and configuration of my template, doesn't work. I work with typo3 10.4.8. Any idea?